# Does YUI datatable datasource work with all valid JSON objects?

Tags: javascript, json, datatable, yui, datasource

First, I should point out that I verified my JSON object with http://jsonlint.com and it is, indeed, valid.

Now that is out of the way, I'm looking at examples of the YUI DataTable, specifically the datasource and the structure of the JSON objects the examples use (see http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/datatable/dt_basic.html).

The Basic Example uses a DataSource composed as follows:

```
YAHOO.example.Data = {
  bookorders: [
    {id:"po-0167", date:new Date(1980, 2, 24), quantity:1, amount:4, title:"A Book About Nothing"},
    {id:"po-0783", date:new Date("January 3, 1983"), quantity:null, amount:12.12345, title:"The Meaning of Life"},
    {id:"po-0297", date:new Date(1978, 11, 12), quantity:12, amount:1.25, title:"This Book Was Meant to Be Read Aloud"},
    {id:"po-1482", date:new Date("March 11, 1985"), quantity:6, amount:3.5, title:"Read Me Twice"}
  ]
}
```

Whereas my JSON object looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "Listing": {
        "Name": "Jay",
        "Address": "Main Street",
        "City": "New York"
    }
  },
  {
    "Listing": {
        "Name": "Thomas",
        "Address": "Union Street",
        "City": "New York"
    }
  },
  {
    "Listing": {
        "Name": "Jason",
        "Address": "Square Street",
        "City": "Boston"
    }
  }
]
```

Here is how Yahoo's example specifies the datasource and a few other lines tied to it:

```
var myDataSource = new YAHOO.util.DataSource(YAHOO.example.Data.bookorders);
myDataSource.responseType = YAHOO.util.DataSource.TYPE_JSARRAY;
myDataSource.responseSchema = {
  fields: ["id","date","quantity","amount","title"]
};
```

In my JSON object, each "Listing" would be a row in the YUI DataTable.  What do I need to modify in the YUI code to make it work with my JSON object?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm also having the same issue. Did you got a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Above you have defined an object, with an unnamed array of objects, each object is composed of another object, with members.  While this might be valid JSON, I don't think this is compatible with the expectations of the YUI datatable.  It is more of a contrived or obfuscated challenge.

I am unable to provide a way, using the existing JSON object.  While your JSON is valid, IMHO, I do not believe it to be compatable with the YUI datatable.

I think you need an object containing a named array of objects that have members, not other objects.  There are too many layers in the existing data structure, that serve no apparent purpose, to me.

'Change', below, implies changing the basic datatable example, provided by YAHOO.

Simply restructuring your data like so,

```
YAHOO.example.Data = {
  Listing: [
    {
          "Name": "Jay",
          "Address": "Main Street",
          "City": "New York"
    },
    {
          "Name": "Thomas",
          "Address": "Union Street",
          "City": "New York"
    },
    {
          "Name": "Jason",
          "Address": "Square Street",
          "City": "Boston"
    }
  ]
};
```

will simplify your data structure and make this work.  This is the minimum change, I believe, considering the constraints.

Then change the datasource:

```
var myDataSource = new YAHOO.util.DataSource(YAHOO.example.Data.Listing);
```

and the column defs

```
var myColumnDefs = [
      {key:"Name"},
      {key:"Address"},
      {key:"City"}
];
```

and finally the response schema

```
myDataSource.responseSchema = {
    fields: ["Name","Address","City"]
};
```

Hope that helps.